# GAMS Optimization

Tags: optimization, simulation, optimal-control

I am writing a GAMS program where I am interested in using the value of a variable as a condition inside an another equation. Let's say I have two equations with two variables, $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$, and they are defined over a set of time $t$. The sample equations are written below:

\begin{align}
g_1(t) &= g_1(t-1)+1 \\
g_2(t) &= g_2(t-1)+20 \;\$\left(g_1(t) \gt 20\right)
\end{align}

To my knowledge, I do not think I can use any variable (endogenous) inside $\$(\cdot)$ operator but if my algorithm demands the way as I mentioned above, is there any way proceed? Or are there any other ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the expression $g_1(t) \gt 20$ with $H \left(g_1(t) - 20\right)$ where $H(\cdot)$ is a step function and can be defined as:

\begin{align}
H(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \gt 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Your solution sounds good if i write in $Matlab$ or $C$ etc. but in $GAMS$, if i try to access any variable in a conditional statement of an equation, it results in an error which state that i can use a parameter but not a variable inside conditional statement.

Comment: I tried your solution but where instead of a dollar operator, i used $H(.)$. \begin{align}
g_1(t) &= g_1(t-1)+1 \\
g_2(t) &= (g_2(t-1)+20)\*H(.)
\end{align} But i got the following error: 145  Set identifier or quoted element expected.

Comment: @Hussain I have not used GAMS before but this sounds frustrating. What if, instead of an exact step function, you approximate it with a sigmoid function? That is continuous and doesn't have any conditionals in it.